# JDK 1.8.0_92 Nashorn JS engine indexOf behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays, java-8, nashorn

I am using "nashorn" javascript engine in java8 to evaluate some expressions during runtime. I have a util class for this with method:

```
    public static String evaluateJavaScriptExpression(String expression) throws ScriptException {
    if (expression == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine javaScriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(JAVASCRIPT_ENGINE);
    return String.valueOf(javaScriptEngine.eval(expression));
}
```

for which I created some unit tests. One of them goes like this:

```
    String expression = "var arr = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]; arr.indexOf(0);";
    assertEquals("-1", ExpressionEvaluatorUtil.evaluateJavaScriptExpression(expression));
```

It worked fine for me while I was using java version "1.8.0_91". But someone who used java version "1.8.0_92" reported that the test is failing. I switched my version to build 92 and it failed for me as well. The actual result for it is "-1.0". 
Also, i tried the same js code in Chrome console and it is returning "-1" as in build 91.

Does anyone know why there is such difference in results between the two jdk versions? Is this a bug or it was purposely changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you know the precise version number of the change, you know where to look: [the list of 1.8u92 bugfixes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u92-bugfixes-2949473.html) lists some fixes regarding Nashorn, the most interesting being [JDK-8144020](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144020):

> #### Remove long as an internal numeric type
>
> ECMA defines double as the only number type in JavaScript. In Nashorn, we internally represent numbers as int, long and double. Use of long is problematic because it adds extra precision to the 53 bits provided by double. …

At the first glance, this seems to be an internal change only, but the picture changes, if you realize that your former result stemmed from the fact that previously, `eval` returned a `Long` for this code, being formatted to `"-1"`.

Now consider the first sentence of this bug report: “*ECMA defines double as the only number type in JavaScript*”. This leads to the conclusion that returning a `Long` was not a specified result type, but an implementation artifact.

So apparently, when `long` was removed from the internal usage, the possibility to return `Long` was eliminated and the engine now doesn’t return `Integer` instead, but `Double`, as a byproduct of the change.

This explains, why there are other scripts like `"var str = 'abcd'; str.indexOf('x');"` which still produce an output without fractional digits. The latter script evaluated to `Integer` and still does. Since the change of the output type was a byproduct of removing internal `long` usage, not an intentional action to change all non-`Double` numeric results, places internally using `int` were not affected.

When comparing the result with Chrome’s engine, you have to consider that you are only comparing formatted output, with the number to string conversion not being part of the script. So the outcome is unspecified. The browser may take the freedom to present all numeric values matching an integer value without fractional digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details.
Just 2 more questions:
1) Why `var str = 'abcd'; str.indexOf('x');` evaluates to Integer and the other code was previously evaluated to Long?
2) Considering everything should be Double, is it a bug as well that str.indexOf() evaluates to Integer and will be removed the same way?

Comment: I don’t know whether the JS array implementation is prepared to handle more than 2³¹ elements or whether there was a different reason. I guess, when it comes to `String` operations, there will be a delegation to Java’s `String.indexOf` somewhere, which returns `int`. I remember having read somewhere, that the only guaranteed return type for Nashorn numeric results is `Number`, so `Integer`, `Long` or `Double` are within that specification. So returning `Integer` is not a bug, but still might change at any time.

Comment: So if you want a stable `String` representation, you should test whether the result is a `Number` and if so, read its `doubleValue()` and test yourself, whether it is representable without fractional part (or always format as double). In other words, not rely on the `toString()` implementation of the number type that happened to be returned…

Answer (score 0):

If we take a look at the [java documentation for ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval-java.lang.String-).eval(String input) method, it returns an object, then it is upto the developer using to typecast the object to correct type as per return type of javascript. So, I think the the problem is with String.valueOf() method call, Evaluation of expression returns a floating point number.

I think you will have to change your code to do Integer.valueOf(javaScriptEngine.eval(expression));

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think you are right about JS returning float number. The tested method is generic and is used in many places, it is not expected to return Integer, so it must always return String. The thing I can't understand is different behaviour in build 91 and 92. Also, I have a similar test like this `var str = 'abcd'; str.indexOf('x');` and it works fine, the returned result is indeed "-1" ! I find it a little confusing.