# Nashorn type conversion confusion between Integer and Double

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, nashorn

If the following program runs under JDK 11:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
System.out.println(engine.eval("var result = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1) + 1; result").getClass());
System.out.println(engine.eval("java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1) + 1").getClass());
```

The results would be:

> class java.lang.Integer
>
> class java.lang.Double

But under JDK8:

> class java.lang.Double
>
> class java.lang.Double

Why is Nashorn changing the type when it's assigned to a variable compared to when it's used directly?

Comment: Interestingly, running it with an early Java 8 version (update 5), gives `java.lang.Integer` for both. This reminds me on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38148917/2711488) (though this is a different change), but it demonstrates that there have been modifications to the returned type more than once.

Comment: Does it matter? javascript only has numbers.

Comment: @MauricePerry that was actually causing an issue when upgrading to JDK 11, and I came upon this root cause. I think at least JDK 8 is doing a justifiable uniform processing, but IMO this is a JDK 11 bug unless I'm not seeing the big picture.